# Itchy miscolored inflammed bump on elbow

Tags: dermatology

For the past 48 hours, I've had a miscolored, raised patch of skin on my elbow that has been itching non-stop.

[image]

I've applied topical diphenhydramine hydrochloride (2%), which seems to have no affect on the itchiness.  The only way to stop the itch has been to wrap it with an ice pack.

What are the possible causes of this?  Could it be serious enough that I need to consult a dermatologist?

Comment: Hello Zephyrus, and welcome. As you can see, this site is not suited for addressing personal situations like this. There is no way for us to know the specifics of your background that might be relevant for making a diagnosis. Please see a medical provider if you are concerned. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper diagnosis would require more questions for your particular situation.  For example:
 - Do you have, or have you had, a fever since you noticed this bump? 
 - Do you any other skin reactions anywhere else on your body? 
 - Did you have any scratches or broken surface of the skin in the area of the bump before you noticed it and the swelling started? 
 - Do you know of insects, ticks, or spiders that may be common in your area? If so, do you feel you may have been exposed to these?

It appears one possibility is a localized reaction resulting from an insect bite. The symptoms you are noticing are common after an arthropod bite, such as local discomfort or pain; pruritis (itchiness); and erythema (redness). Because there is blanching in the center with a ring of erythema around this, it may suggest a bite.

Another less likely possibility is cellulitis. Cellulitis is an infection of the skin and subcutaneous layer of tissue just below the skin. This can result from trauma to the skin such as a cut or a bite, when bacteria are able to enter through the disturbed skin surface. However, accompanying symptoms also include tenderness/pain at the site; chills; fever; and swollen lymph nodes near the site.

Ibuprofen (e.g. Motrin) taken orally should help decrease inflammation around the site of the swelling, thereby alleviating some of the itching and discomfort. The topical corticosteroids available over the counter may not be in the strength you need to counter an inflammatory or allergic reaction.  Due to this, it would be prudent to consult your health care provider if this does not start to resolve within the next 24 hours as it sometimes may two to three days for the initial symptoms to subside if this resulted from a bite. Also, if you develop other symptoms such as fever, nausea, decreased appetite, fatigue, or hives you should see your provider right away.

http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/insectbitesandstings.html
http://www.uptodate.com/contents/skin-and-soft-tissue-infection-cellulitis-beyond-the-basics?view=print

Comment: People should stop answering these kind of questions...the question is obviously out of scope.

Comment: Celulitis is not usually itchy, but rather tender, whereas insect bites are definitely itchy.